# Is Data Mart Normalized ? if Yes then What is the normal form of Data Mart?

Tags: database, data-warehouse, olap, data-analysis

I read a lot about data mart and know that data mart uses star and snowflake schema. But I want to know that what is normal form of Data Mart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a data warehouse is not normalized

A data warehouse uses dimensional design and should be highly **de**normalized to facilitate analysis

Your operational database (like for an e-commerce site) uses relational design and should be highly normalized to minimize update anomalies